# Minimal cost path of 2d matrix

Tags: python, shortest-path

I am trying to find the minimal cost path from point (0, 0) to point {(u, v) | u + v <= 100} in a 2d matrix of data I have generated.

My algorithm is pretty simple and currently I have managed to produce the following (visualized) results, which leads me to understand that I am way off in my algorithm.
[image]

```
# each cell of path_arr contains a tuple of (i,j) of the next cell in path.
# data contains the "cost" of stepping on its cell
# total_cost_arr is used to assist reconstructing the path.
def min_path(data, m=100, n=100):
    total_cost_arr = np.array([np.array([0 for x in range(0, m)]).astype(float) for x in range(0, n)])
    path_arr = np.array([np.array([(0, 0) for x in range(0, m)], dtype='i,i') for x in range(0, n)])
    total_cost_arr[0, 0] = data[0][0]

    for i in range(0, m):
        total_cost_arr[i, 0] = total_cost_arr[i - 1, 0] + data[i][0]

    for j in range(0, n):
        total_cost_arr[0, j] = total_cost_arr[0, j - 1] + data[0][j]

    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            total_cost_arr[i, j] = min(total_cost_arr[i - 1, j - 1], total_cost_arr[i - 1, j], total_cost_arr[i, j - 1]) + data[i][j]
            if total_cost_arr[i, j] == total_cost_arr[i - 1, j - 1] + data[i][j]:
                path_arr[i - 1, j - 1] = (i, j)
            elif total_cost_arr[i, j] == total_cost_arr[i - 1, j] + data[i][j]:
                path_arr[i - 1, j] = (i, j)
            else:
                path_arr[i, j - 1] = (i, j)
```

each cell of path_arr contains a tuple of (i,j) of the next cell in path.
data contains the "cost" of stepping on its cell, and
total_cost_arr is used to assist reconstructing the path.

I think that placing (i,j) in previous cell is causing some conflicts which lead to this behavior.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The colors in the picture indicate the distance to each point in the upper-left half of the grid? What is the meaning of the mis-colored pixels near the top-left corner? Is this the path? Or is this mis-coloring what you say is "way off" in the algorithm?

Comment: @gspr How should I approach this as my current approach is incorrect.

Comment: @tobias_k you are correct, the miscoloring is my way off algorithm. The coloring is the cost of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an array is the best structure for your problem.

You should use some graph data structure (with [networkx for example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html)) and use algorithm like the [Dijkstra one's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (derivated from the first one).

The Dijkstra algorithm is implemented in netwokrkx ([function for shortest path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length.html)).

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented Dikstra's algorithm following your advise. Hopefully it is working correctly.